# API to return "Configuration Specific" properties of SolidWorks files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am currently looking at the article [Solidworks Configuration Properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-configuration-specific-properties-solidworks-files).

Once a part is uploaded we use the modelderivative API to extract the part information, this additional config data does not seem to be accessible anywhere through these APIs.

Is there another endpoint to call to be able to extract this data or is the only implementation currently handled through the viewer as demoed in the article?

Cheers

Comment: While it is true that the viewer gets the metadata from its own "property database", I believe the database gets the data in the same way as the Model Derivative APIs. Which API endpoint are you using specifically? And could you perhaps share the SolidWorks file you're trying to process?

Comment: We currently use two modelderivative API endpoints for collecting our part :urn/metadata/:guid and :urn/metadata/:guid/properties.

Running the getActiveConfigurationProperties() code from the article I can see the extra properties being returned to the console. They are not found in either of the two endpoints we are currently using that return the other part data we have used so far.